# centos7 ssh Host Key Verification failed

Tags: php, linux, centos

I'm writting a php script in my server i want to do some opertions using Shell_exec

But each time i try to run this i'm receving an error as "Could not create directory '/usr/share/httpd/.ssh'.
Host key verification failed."

the code which throws the above error is `shell_exec("ssh -p 9363 root@localhost mkdir /etc/pmta/testing1");`

Comment: Also when u execute this command directly through terminal. It works fine

Comment: Does the ssh login require a password?  If yes, can you disable password-based authentication and then try?